# Issues with using classList to hide and show elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to implement a feature where a div shows up when another div is clicked and should hide if the div is clicked again.

Here is the fiddle with a small portion of the code : https://jsfiddle.net/6dgL6zqb/1/

```
var portfolio = document.getElementById('portfolio');
EventUtil.addHandler(portfolio, 'click', function(event) {
event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
var target = EventUtil.getTarget(event);

switch(target.id) {
    case 'kk':
        console.log('kk clicked');
        var idName = target.id + 'Details',
        doc = document,
        currentProject = doc.getElementById(idName),
        otherProjects = doc.getElementsByClassName('projectDetails');
        console.log(currentProject);
        for (var i = otherProjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var projectClassList = otherProjects.item(i).classList;
            if (projectClassList.contains('showMe')) {
                projectClassList.remove('showMe');
                projectClassList.add('hideMe');
            }
        };
        var currentProjectClassList = currentProject.classList;
        console.log(currentProjectClassList);
        if (!currentProjectClassList.contains('showMe')) {
            currentProjectClassList.remove('hideMe');
            currentProjectClassList.add('showMe');
        } else {
            currentProjectClassList.remove('showMe');
            currentProjectClassList.add('hideMe');
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

I am using an EventUtil handler to handle events, along-with event delegation.

So, when I click on Section 1 with the id 'kk', another div with id 'kkDetails' displays. But, I expect the div with id 'kkDetails' to disappear when I click on the div with id 'kk'. How can I get that to happen?

As far as I can see, the currentProjectClassList object is not updating as I expect. Although, I don't understand why.

PS: I am new at programming, so please bear with any ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There problem that you are having is this section:

```
  otherProjects = doc.getElementsByClassName('projectDetails');
  for (var i = otherProjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var projectClassList = otherProjects.item(i).classList;
            if (projectClassList.contains('showMe')) {
                projectClassList.remove('showMe');
                projectClassList.add('hideMe');
            }
        };
```

You are actually hiding your element and then later showing it again, as an example modify this section to be something like:

```
      otherProjects = doc.getElementsByClassName('projectDetails');
      for (var i = otherProjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(otherProjects.item(i).id !== idName){
                    var projectClassList = otherProjects.item(i).classList;
                    if (projectClassList.contains('showMe')) {
                        projectClassList.remove('showMe');
                        projectClassList.add('hideMe');
                    } 
                }
            };
```

In this section you are swapping the visible state of your selected div:

```
    if (!currentProjectClassList.contains('showMe')) {
        currentProjectClassList.remove('hideMe');
        currentProjectClassList.add('showMe');
    } else {
        currentProjectClassList.remove('showMe');
        currentProjectClassList.add('hideMe');
    }
```

however in the previous section of code because your selected element also has the class *projectDetails* it gets its *showMe* removed and *hideMe* added. So when it gets to section of code above this if(!currentProjectClassList.contains('showMe')) will always be true.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, the whole thing was happening twice. Always pays to have a fresh look at the code. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single class to toggle visibility. It is a lot more manageable. Also I would link click element with the toggled element via an attribute of some kind (instead of using a switch statement in javascript).

```
EventUtil.addHandler(portfolio, 'click', function(event) {
  event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
  var target = EventUtil.getTarget(event);
  var divId = target.getAttribute('href');

  if (divId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Array
      .from(document.querySelectorAll('.projectDetails:not(.hideMe)'))
      .forEach(function(a) {
        a.classList.add('hideMe')
      });

    document.querySelector(divId).classList.remove('hideMe')
  }
});
```

```js
// Cross-browser event handler
var EventUtil = {
  addHandler: function(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
      element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
    } else {
      element["on" + type] = handler;
    }
  },

  getEvent: function(event) {
    return event ? event : window.event;
  },

  getTarget: function(event) {
    return event.target || event.srcElement;
  },

  preventDefault: function(event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      event.returnValue = false;
    }
  },

  removeHandler: function(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.removeEventListener) {
      element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (element.detachEvent) {
      element.detachEvent("on" + type, handler);
    } else {
      element["on" + type] = null;
    }
  },

  stopPropagation: function(event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
  }
};

var portfolio = document.getElementById('portfolio');
EventUtil.addHandler(portfolio, 'click', function(event) {
  event = EventUtil.getEvent(event);
  var target = EventUtil.getTarget(event);
  var divId = target.getAttribute('href');

  if (divId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Array
      .from(document.querySelectorAll('.projectDetails:not(.hideMe)'))
      .forEach(function(a) {
        a.classList.add('hideMe')
      });

    document.querySelector(divId).classList.remove('hideMe')
  }
});
```

```css
.projectDetails {
  display: block;
}
.projectDetails.hideMe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <section id="portfolio">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <a href="#kkDetails" id="kk">Section 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <a href="#arthDetails">Section 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <a href="#bobyPinzDetails">Section 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="kkDetails" class="hideMe projectDetails">
          <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="arthDetails" class="hideMe projectDetails">
          <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bobyPinzDetails" class="hideMe projectDetails">
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But, if I click the second time, the hideMe class is first added and then removed. Hence, the div wont hide when it is showing. Um, do you see what I am saying?

Comment: Right this code does not support hiding if open, but it would be easy to check if the `targetdiv.classList.contains('hideMe')` before doing anything, and if it doesn't have the class that means it's already open and you can do different code.